# Jsonschema to validate at least one of the lists is present

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a json, like this:

```
{
  "listA": [
    {
      "prop1": "mine"
    },
     {
      "prop1": "mine"
    }
  ],
  "listB": [
    {
      "prop1": "mine"
    }
  ],
  "propsForAll": {
    "property1": "value",
    "property2": "value"
  }
}
```

I need json schema to validate that at least one of the types of lists is present {listA, listB, listC}

This is the bit of my json schema, that I am trying to create, but `python` `jsonschema` is simply saying that "[the content of the json] is not valid under any of the given schemas":

```
....  
"required": [
    "propsForAll"
  ],
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/properties/listA"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/properties/listB"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/properties/listC"
    }
  ],
....
```

If I remove the anyOf section, the validation passes, but it is not checking what I need.
Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ref` isn't the right thing here. You want to use `required` instead.

```
{
  "required": ["propsForAll"],
  "anyOf": [
    { "required": ["listA"] },
    { "required": ["listB"] },
    { "required": ["listC"] }
  ]
}
```

With `$ref` you are saying that the instance must must *be* "listA" or "listB" or "listC" rather than it must *contain* "listA" or "listB" or "listC".